# jquery mobile - Collapsible in footer expands down after a click on page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, footer, jquery-mobile-collapsible

Hey guys I am learning jquery mobile and have created a very basic page with a header and a footer. Basically I want the footer collapsible to **always expand upwards** but I am having problems achieving this.

If I load the page and open the collapsible by clicking on the button it expands up (the expected behavior).
But if I click any where on the page and then click on the footer, it expands downwards.  It seems like clicking on the page detaches the footer even though I am using `data-position="fixed"`  adding this tag to the collapsible itself does not change the behavior.

Also clicking again on the page reattaches it and it opens upwards.

I can always force it by using css.  But I would like to know if there is a better way of fixing this.

I cannot provide a jsfiddle because the problem only happens in the browser (i have tested with chrome, firefox and android browser on droid razr).  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="Page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="b">
                <h3>Footer</h3>
                <p>Footer content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>


<html>
```

Comment: IMHO, having a collapsible in footer isn't a good idea.

Comment: Is there a better way of achieving this behavior?  Basically I want something like a info page that expands from the bottom (takes up about half the page height, if the content is too much then it should scroll) and is present across multiple pages so I thought a footer would be a good starting point. Like I said, I am learning so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You could do something like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/YgJkN/

Comment: added  some transitions to @Omar s fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/YgJkN/2/
:)

Comment: @Omar as far as the original question.  Why is it a bad idea to have a collapsible in a footer?

Comment: Because it won't react the way you want. Collapsibles expand/collapse its bottom, not top. This way it will cause footer to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

While working on something similar today.  I stumbled upon the same problem and fixed it by adding

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

to the div.